# Two or more buttons triggering the same Material-UI Popper element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So, I got into a situation where I need to trigger the same Material-UI `<Popper />` component from multiple different clickable elements.

As is it is [described on the Popper component API](https://material-ui.com/api/popper/) on Material-UI website, when calling the Popper component you might want to pass a property named `anchorEl` which defines where the popper will be positioned on the canvas. My intention is for that `anchorEl` to always be the same, thus the popper will always open at the same position on the UI.

Most of the examples on Material-UI documentation suggest the following approach for using Popper:

```js
const SimplePopper = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>
      <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first problem with this usage is that your code depends on the `handleClick` function to be called for it to define the `anchorEl` state value.

The second problem is that, even if you have more than one button element calling the `handleClick` function, the value on `event.currentTarget` would vary and the `Popper` element would show up in different positions of the canvas.

So, the question is:

How could I have two or more buttons triggering the same `<Popper />` element in a way it always renders under the same `anchorEl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add a `ref` to the anchor element and pass it to `Popper` and use a state variable to manage the popper open state. You can then toggle the open state when the trigger elements are clicked.

```
const App = () => {
  const anchorRef = useRef(null)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle Popper</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} ref={anchorRef}>
        Toggle Popper
      </Button>

      <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorRef.current}>
        The content of the Popper.
      </Popper>
    </>
  )
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-shamir-z48et?file=/src/App.js)